# Visual Studio Code: How to access local script file from webview

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, content-security-policy

I cannot figure out how to get passed CSP to load local JS files in my extension in a webview.

### Source HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
            content="img-src 'self' data: https: http: blob: ${baseUrl}; default-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' vscode-resource: data: https: http: blob:;">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <base>${baseUrl}</head>
        <title>Extension Sets</title>
        <style>
            .disabled {
                filter: brightness(0.2)
            }

            summary h2 {
                display: inline-block;
            }

            .grid_container {
                display: grid;
                grid-gap: 10px;
                position: fixed;
                top: 150px;
                left: 8px;
                right: 8px;
                bottom: 8px;
            }

            header {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                height: 110px;
                padding: 10px;
                background-color: var(--vscode-focusBorder);
                color: var(--vscode-textSeparator-foreground);
            }

            header h1 {
                color: var(--vscode-foreground);
            }

            div.grid_box {
                grid-row: 1;
            }

            #all {
                grid-column-start: 1;
                grid-column-end: 1;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: var(--vscode-activityBar-background) brightness(25%);
                overflow-y: scroll;
            }

            #filtered {
                grid-column-start: 2;
                grid-column-end: 2;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: var(--vscode-activityBar-background) brightness(25%);
                overflow-y: scroll;
            }

            .title {
                font-weight: bolder;
                font-size: larger;
                background-color: grayscale(0.20);
            }

            details {
                margin: 5px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                padding: 4px;
                background-color: var(--vscode-activityBar-background);
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <H1>Extension Sets</H1>
            <input type="search" title="Find installed extension." id="txtSearch" />
            <button class="btn"
                onclick="document.sendFind([{ __type: 'Language', Data: { Value: document.getElementById('txtSearch').value } }])">Search</button>
        </header>
        <article>
            <main class="grid_container">

                <div id="all" class="grid_box">
                    <h1>All Extensions</h1>
                </div>
                <div id="filtered" class="grid_box">
                    <H1>Filtered</H1>
                </div>
            </main>
            <script type="module" src="${baseUrl}out/extension.js"></script>
            <script type="module" src="${baseUrl}out/browser.js"></script>
        </article>
    </body>

</html>
```

### Code that renders the html

```js
function fixWebviewLinks(document: string, documentPath: string, webView: vscode.Webview): string {
    return document.replace(
        new RegExp('((?:src|href)=[\'\"])(.*?)([\'\"])', 'gmi'),
        (subString: string, p1: string, p2: string, p3: string): string => {
            const lower = p2.toLowerCase();
            if (p2.startsWith('#') || lower.startsWith('http://') || lower.startsWith('https://')) {
                return subString;
            }
            const index = p2.indexOf('?');
            if (index > - 1) {
                p2 = p2.substr(0, index);
            }
            const newPath = vscode.Uri.file(path.join(path.dirname(documentPath), p2));
            const newUrl = [
                p1,
                webView.asWebviewUri(newPath),
                p3,
            ].join('');
            return newUrl;
        },
    );
}

// In my activate method
        var localPath = this.Context.asAbsolutePath("out") ;
        const csp = this.WebView.cspSource + "/";
        let html: string = readFileSync(this.Index()).toString();
        let match: RegExpMatchArray | null = html.match(/\$\{baseUrl\}/);
        let isMatch: boolean = (match?.length ?? 0) > 0;

        while (isMatch) {
            html = html.replace(/\$\{baseUrl\}/, csp);

            match = html.match(/\$\{baseUrl\}/);
            isMatch = (match?.length ?? 0) > 0;
        }

        html = fixWebviewLinks(html, localPath, this.WebView);

        this.WebView.html = html;
```

### Rendered HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
            content="img-src 'self' data: https: http: blob: https://*.vscode-webview.net/; default-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' vscode-resource: data: https: http: blob:;">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <base>https://*.vscode-webview.net/</head>
        <title>Extension Sets</title>
        <style>
            .disabled {
                filter: brightness(0.2)
            }

            summary h2 {
                display: inline-block;
            }

            .grid_container {
                display: grid;
                grid-gap: 10px;
                position: fixed;
                top: 150px;
                left: 8px;
                right: 8px;
                bottom: 8px;
            }

            header {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                height: 110px;
                padding: 10px;
                background-color: var(--vscode-focusBorder);
                color: var(--vscode-textSeparator-foreground);
            }

            header h1 {
                color: var(--vscode-foreground);
            }

            div.grid_box {
                grid-row: 1;
            }

            #all {
                grid-column-start: 1;
                grid-column-end: 1;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: var(--vscode-activityBar-background) brightness(25%);
                overflow-y: scroll;
            }

            #filtered {
                grid-column-start: 2;
                grid-column-end: 2;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: var(--vscode-activityBar-background) brightness(25%);
                overflow-y: scroll;
            }

            .title {
                font-weight: bolder;
                font-size: larger;
                background-color: grayscale(0.20);
            }

            details {
                margin: 5px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                padding: 4px;
                background-color: var(--vscode-activityBar-background);
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <H1>Extension Sets</H1>
            <input type="search" title="Find installed extension." id="txtSearch" />
            <button class="btn"
                onclick="document.sendFind([{ __type: 'Language', Data: { Value: document.getElementById('txtSearch').value } }])">Search</button>
        </header>
        <article>
            <main class="grid_container">

                <div id="all" class="grid_box">
                    <h1>All Extensions</h1>
                </div>
                <div id="filtered" class="grid_box">
                    <H1>Filtered</H1>
                </div>
            </main>
            <script type="module" src="https://*.vscode-webview.net/out/extension.js"></script>
            <script type="module" src="https://*.vscode-webview.net/out/browser.js"></script>
        </article>
    </body>

</html>
```

Edit 1: Replaced the HTML with the full rendered html.
Edit 2: Added the method to fix the links nper comment.

### Console shows

```
main.js:845 GET https://%2A.vscode-webview.net/out/extension.js net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
(anonymous) @   main.js:845
setTimeout (async)      
v   @   main.js:843
(anonymous) @   main.js:874
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You will have to patch the HTML by replacing normal links with webview friendly links, https://github.com/vscode-restructuredtext/vscode-restructuredtext/blob/6f048a34dfba987fb777accb6de73c12e8a1ae4d/src/preview/rstEngine.ts#L171

Comment: @LexLi I made your suggested changes, but no help.  I've updated the question.